# Simplification of Expression with Standard Normal CDF

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Let $\Phi(x)$ be the CDF of the standard normal distribution. For $a,x\in\mathbb{R}$, can the following expression:

$$(\Phi(x)-\Phi(-x))(1-(\Phi(x)-\Phi(-x)))$$

be simplified into something a littler nicer to work with?  What is the simplest form of this expression?

Comment: It looks pretty simple to me. In english, it's the area under the standard normal curve from $-x$ to $x$ times the area under the curve that is not from $-x$ to $x$.

Comment: Yeah, but I'm just not seeing the algebra to make this easier to work with.

Comment: Use $\phi (-x) = 1- \phi(x)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Youem points out, $\Phi(-x)=1-\Phi(x)$ but this substitution saves minimal time:

$$\begin{align*}
(\Phi(x)-\Phi(-x))\cdot(1-(\Phi(x)-\Phi(-x)))
&=(\Phi(x)-(1-\Phi(x)))\cdot(1-(\Phi(x)-(1-\Phi(x))))\\\\
&=(2\Phi(x)-1)\cdot(-2\Phi(x)+2)\\\\
&=-4\Phi(x)^2+6\Phi(x)-2
\end{align*}$$

The original expression is more interpretable as well.

Comment: Thanks, disappointing that it couldn't be simplified further.